# group law of Elliptic curve with taking two point at infinity

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

We often describe group law on elliptic curve, like 'taking two points from $E$, and then line it rhrough infinity, and the line intersects with another new point, and line through the new point with infinity.
In particular, if we take two points at the same point of affine chart of $E$, the first line is the tangent at the overlapping first two points.
But what happen when we take first two points of the line at infinity?
How can I describe the group law on this case? In particular, what is the first line of the overlapping first two points at infinity?

Comment: An elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ should be thought of as a projective curve, $\{y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3\}\subseteq\mathbb P^3$. The point at infinity is then the point $[0:1:0]$, and you have to consider the tangent line at this point.

Comment: I know that but how can I visualize it , for example, if the field is real field?

Comment: You can think of it like this. Substitute $z=0$ in $y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3$ so you get $x^3=0$. So the line $z=0$ (the line at infinity) intersects the elliptic curve $3$ times.

Comment: Oh, thank you. The line I was looking for is just $Z＝0$. We cannot see the line in affine chart, but it really exists in projective plane. Could I ask one more? In affine chart $Z＝1$, in which direction the line exists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but $z=1$ doesn't really make sense in projective space (while $z\ne0$ does.)

Comment: Yes, but we may be able to image it in a meaning like a kind of ultimate form, let take one point $P$ from affine chart, we often line through it with infinity, like a line through $P$ and x-axisis symmetry of $P$, although the infinite point does not exists in affine chart, I call this  'visualize' in affine chart. In this meaning, how can I visualize the situation of the tangent line at infinity in affine chart?

Comment: There is a unique projective line going through $P$ and $[0:1:0]$, and you can take the intersection of that with the elliptic curve. (If $P=[1:1:1]$, for instance, the line $x=z$ goes through both.)

Comment: You mean $P＝[a:b:1]$ is on elliptic curve  for instance, then, a line $x＝a$ also go through $[1:1:0]$ and $P$, so this line is visible in affine chart $Z＝1$, but we cannot see the line $Z＝0$ because it does not go through any points in affine chart, right ?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are saying, but I think you have the idea.